# Calculate allele frequencies from posterior mean genotypes

Tags: arrays, awk, bioinformatics

In the following file (input_file.txt):

```
col1, col2, col3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.002, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1.9, 0, 0.1, 2, 1, 0, 0.8
```

posterior mean genotypes (PMGs) are 0-2, or NA (the first 3 columns do not contain PMGs).

Therefore, input_file.txt has PMG information for 21 individuals (=Number of fields (NF) -3).

To calculate allele frequency based on the information contained within input_file.txt, we first need to do some pre-processing and hold some values in memory.

As stated, PMGs can range from 0-2 but each of these values represent one of only three genotypes:

- 0 to <0.5 = homozygous reference
- 0.5 to <1.5 = heterozygous
- 1.5 to 2 = homozygous alternate

So we next need to convert the PMGs into genotypes in input_file.txt

Something like:

```
for NF >3 && column value !=NA 
if "column value" = 0 to <0.5, replace value with 0 (= homozygous reference)
if "column value" = 0.5 to <1.5, replace value with 1 (= heterozygous)
if "column value" = 1.5 to 2, replace value with 2 (= homozygous alternate)
```

intermediate output:

```
col1, col2, col3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1
```

so we have non-NA PMGs for 14 of 21 individuals.

I can determine the counts using:

```
awk -F, ' NF>3 {print (split($0,a,"NA")-1) }' input_file.txt > NA_count
awk -F, ' NF>3 {print (split($0,a,"0")-1) }' input_file.txt > ref_count
awk -F, ' NF>3 {print (split($0,a,"1")-1) }' input_file.txt > het_count
awk -F, ' NF>3 {print (split($0,a,"2")-1) }' input_file.txt > alt_count
```

To get allele frequency from this data:
(ref_count + het_count + 2*alt_count)/2*(ref_count + het_count + alt_count)

which is the same as:
0+0+0+0+1+0+1+2+0+0+2+1+0+1/2(14) = 8/28 = 0.286 = allele frequency

Desired output:

"col1", 8/28, 0.286

Please note that input files can have a variable number of columns, in which there will be a variable number of 0-2 and NA values.

The intermediate output shown above is not a requirement per se (need only desired output)

awk code preferred but not essential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
       {for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) if($i!="NA") a[$i=int($i+0.5)]++}
   1;
   END {print "\""$1"\"", (n=a[1]+2*a[2])"/"(d=2*(a[0]+a[1]+a[2])),n/d}' file

col1, col2, col3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1
"col1", 8/28, 0.285714
```

to filter the intermediate result, remove `1;` from the code.